# Jsoup connection problems with Android application

Tags: java, android, jsoup

So I am using Jsoup for my project. The backend code is working fine on the output menu but when I am trying to put it on the android studio, it is not working. I imported the libraries perfectly and no error in the code. I also gave access to the internet using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

So I thought of making a new mini-project. So now my code looks like

```
'''
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button button;
    public TextView textview;
    public EditText edittext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        View.OnClickListener search = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.flipkart.com").get();
                    String title = doc.text();
                    textview.append(title);

                } catch (Exception e){

                }
            }
        };
        button.setOnClickListener(search);
    }
} '''
```

But nothing is printing in the text view. Please tell me the mistake.

Comment: Your code is working. Use edittext.append(title); Then you can see.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir no it is not working for me. What did you do? And I created a textview to append. Edit text is of no use right now.

Comment: It can be NetworkOnMainThreadException. I found a solution and added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
Executor mExecutor  = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

Tasks.call(mExecutor, new Callable<String>() {
     @Override
     public String call() throws Exception {
         Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.flipkart.com").get();
         String title = doc.text();
         return title;
     }
}).continueWith(new Continuation<String, Object>() {

     @Override
     public Object then(@NonNull Task<String> task) throws Exception {
         textview.append( task.getResult());
         return null;
     }
});
```

> Using Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() on the other hand allows you
>   to submit multiple tasks.

Comment: So after you gave me this solution, I looked at the exception and I used AysncTask. That helped me. So thank you for providing the exception. Thanks.

Comment: AysncTask was deprecated in API level R. AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.